Innovative Adjustable Dumbbell Concept: Seeking Expert Advice
I'm a student with an innovative idea for gym equipment, specifically adjustable dumbbells. My concept aims to solve space, hygiene, and progression issues in gyms:
Instead of multiple sets of fixed-weight dumbbells, there would be a few adjustable models (e.g., XS: 1-5kg, S: 6-10kg, up to Ronnie: 46-50kg).
Each dumbbell would have a display and controls to easily adjust the weight.
The external appearance and size would remain constant regardless of the selected weight.
The weight change would occur internally, possibly using magnetism or a mechanical system.
Benefits include space efficiency, improved hygiene, easier progressive overload, and a wider range of available weights.
As someone without an engineering background or access to prototyping resources, I'm seeking advice:
How feasible do you think this concept is from an engineering perspective?
What potential challenges or obstacles do you foresee?
As a student with limited resources, what steps would you recommend I take to develop this idea further?
Are there any similar technologies or patents I should be aware of?
How might I protect this idea while seeking expert input and potential partnerships?
Any insights, suggestions, or feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

How would this improve hygiene? or is it a "bring your own handle" concept? perhaps extend it to "bring your own b*g seat"?

I 'lost access' to unregistered account, please go here https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61614/modern-adjustable-dumbbell-concept-seeking-expert-advice.

Engineering is feasible in that its been done before. Marketing and safety suffer. More parts means more parts that can fail or get lost- would suck to have weights available but no handles.  Single piece solution follows KISS.

Understood. Since there are no answers on the original question I just closed that one.
